# I wonder about differences between using `useEffect()` with empty dependency array and not using `useEffect()` itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I know `useEffect()` with no array run the callback only at the first render.

Then what is the differences between `useEffect(()=>{},[])` and no `useEffect()`.

I mean between this:

```
function myComponent() {
  // some states, variables

  useEffect(() => {
    // do something on mount <= this is my current concern.
  }, [/* empty */]);

  // return Element ...
}
```

and this:

```
function myComponent() {
  // some states, variables

  // do something on mount <= this is my current concern.
  
  // return Element ...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In React, a component re-renders whenever there is a change in it's state or one of it's props.
The reason it behaves like this is so that it would be possible to "react" to a change in the mentioned data, and to reflect UI changes accordingly.

Every time the component re-renders, so does any logic within it that is not cached (functions, variables, etc..)

`useEffect` helps us with reacting to a change in the state or props that are stated in it's dependency array.
It gives us to option to automatically run a callback function in such an event/s.

`useEffect` with an empty dependency array, will run only a single time when the component is mounted.

**So in this example -**

```js
function myComponent() {
  // some states, variables

  useEffect(() => {
    // do something on mount <= this is my current concern.
  }, [/* empty */]);

  // return Element ...
}
```

The callback function inside the `useEffect` will run only once, when the component is first "brought to life".
Subsequent renders will not invoke this.

**While in this example -**

```js
function myComponent() {
  // some states, variables

  // do something on mount <= this is my current concern.
  
  // return Element ...
}
```

Whatever you put in there will run every time the component re-renders.
Whether this is ok or not depends on your use-case and what function are you trying to run, if it's "cheap" to run or not, etc..

Comment: There is an error in your statement that "In React, a component re-renders whenever there is a change in it's state or one of it's props." This is not true. According to [this](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#standard-render-behavior), In normal rendering, React does not care whether "props changed" - it will render child components unconditionally just because the parent rendered

Comment: True, though we can prevent that from happening with memoization, etc..  
The bottom line is, however, that if a prop changes, the component does indeed re-render, so how is that not true? i.e. - in effect, the component still re-renders...

Comment: Good point, the statement is not "false", just misleading. Components re-render when props change, but also when a parent is rendered (which will happen even if a component has 0 props)

Comment: You are right. I think it's also safe to explain it like I did, because it's easier to understand and remember for beginners IMO. But you definitely said it more accurately.

Answer (score 2):

```
function myComponent() {
   useEffect(() => {
   }, []);

}
```

here `useEffect(()=>{},[])` works like componentDidMount

and

```
function myComponent() {
}
```

this is normal js function

Answer (score 1):

They will be executed every time at component re-render if you put them in function directly

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, when you have an empty dependency (like below), the code inside will only run on mount.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    something() // only runs on mount
  }, []);
```

If you don't have a `useEffect` at all, the code will be run every time the component rerenders.

```
function myComponent() {
  // some states, variables

  something() // runs on every rerender
  
  // return ...
}
```

Now the question is, "when does a rerender happen?". In general, anytime a parent component renders, React will rerender all children of that component. So rerenders can occur quite often.

Look at [this article](https://alexsidorenko.com/blog/react-render-always-rerenders), which has some really helpful visual examples of when components rerender.

Answer (score 1):

if the dependency array is empty you will only run the useEffect on mount. While not using useEffect, the code inside your component will run every time you rerender the page/component.

```
function myComponent(){
   console.log('render') // will run everytime you render
   return ()
}


function myComponent(){
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('on mount'); // run on mount
  }, [])
  return ()
}
```